Compute the flux of a vector across an intersecting plane
I have trouble in this problem:

Let $S$ be the surface obtained by intersecting $x^2+ y^2 \leq 1$ with $x+2y+z = 5$, and let $F = 2x\mathbf i - z\mathbf j + x\mathbf k$. Suppose that $S$ is given upwards pointing orientation. Then compute the flux of $F$ upwards across $S$.

First, I find that: $x^2+y^2 \leq 1$ is a solid cylinder in $\mathbb R^3$. It is a cylinder with its centre running along the $z$-axis and with radius $1$. Then, $x+2y+z = 5$ is a plane in $\mathbb R^3$, so it is slicing this cylinder with a plane and computing the flux across this slice. But then when computing the flux I got $-8\pi$, which is wrong.

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

I have fixed your editing (please try to use MathJax to format equations). If any commenters here can remind me of the LaTeX for the double-strike R that would be great (I left it as a capital R in the edit but know it should be a double-strike R).

@RedFive it’s \mathbb R

@RedFive Thanks a lot!

I suspect @ehceb helped quite a bit with the edits...

Please show how you got $-8\pi$ and what someone says that the correct solution is.

@KurtG. First I find the normal vector of the plane , which is (1,2,1), then I calculate the dot product, and use cylindrical coordinates to compute the integral, but the answer is −8π. The correct solution is -10π.

The plane $x+2y+z=5$ is parametrized by
$$
(x,y)\mapsto\pmatrix{x\\y\\5-x-2y}\,,\quad x^2+y^2\le 1\,.
$$
As explained here, $\mathbf{n}\,dS$ is
$$
\mathbf{n}\,dS=\pmatrix{1\\0\\-1}\times\pmatrix{0\\1\\-2}\,dx\,dy=\pmatrix{1\\2\\1}\,dx\,dy\,.
$$
Then the integral is
$$
\int_{plane} F\cdot\mathbf{n}\,dS=\int\limits_{x^2+y^2\le 1}(2x-2z+x)\,dx\,dy=\int\limits_{x^2+y^2\le 1}x-2(5-x-2y)\,dx\,dy=-10\,\pi\,
$$
because the terms containing $x$ or $y$ in the integrand are zero.

Thanks you! Now I realize that I did not change z to to 5-x-2y when computing the integral, thus the result is wrong.
